# Why the integral $\int_{\mathbb{R^n}}e^{-iAx} \hat{\phi} (-g(x))$ is well defined?

Tags: calculus, fourier-transform

> Let $\phi$ be a smooth function on $\mathbb{R}^n$ with compact support. Let $ g : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be a smooth map such that there exists $c>0$ and $ k \in \mathbb{N} -\lbrace0\rbrace $ such that $ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $||g(x)|| \geq c {||x||}^k$.  Let $A$ be a square matrix. How can we show that the map  $$ x \mapsto e^{-iAx} \hat{\phi} (-g(x))$$
> decreases rapidly, which implies that the integral
> $$ \int_{\mathbb{R^n} }e^{-iAx} \hat{\phi} (-g(x)) dx$$  is well defined?

Comment: I think you need to check your functions. I don't understand how $f$ plays a role for example.

Comment: Oops! I made a mistake, I'll edit my post.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I'm sorry, I realize now that I have forgotten to mention that $A$ is nilpotent.

Comment: By $dx$ do you mean the $n$ dimensional infinitesimal measure in $\mathbb{R}^n$ at $x$? Or some sort of line element?

Comment: @K.defaoite,  yes I mean the n dimensional infinitesimal measure in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: @pax: $\hat{\phi}$ is a Schwartz function, so everything should be fine.

Comment: @Phoemuex, could you give further details please! I actually don't understand how to use the boundedness of $g$ and the fact that $A$ is nilpotent (however, I think that $A$ is nilpotent serves to say that $e^{-iAx}$ has a polynomial behavior).

Comment: @PhoemueX Ah yes, I was wrong.

Comment: Is $A$ a real or complex matrix? If it is real, you don't even need it to be nilpotent, I think.

Comment: Yes, it's real and it's nilpotent ! Why don't we need it to be nilpotent if it's real?